# How to turn entry value into variable in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a simple bank account program on Python, i have already coded it (more than what is shown) , and now i am using that to create a GUI out of it, i am new to Python let alone Tkinter. How would i get the entry value from "Text" and turn it into a variable so i can print it.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
balance = (randint(100, 500))


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        toolbar = Frame(root)
        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        button1 = Button(toolbar, text="Deposit", width = 13, command=self.printBalance)
        button2 = Button(toolbar, text="Withdraw",width = 13, command=self.printBalance)

        button1.pack(side=LEFT)
        button2.pack(side=RIGHT)


        subMenu = Menu(menu)
        menu.add_cascade(label="Type of Account", menu=subMenu)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Standard", command= self.printBalance)
        subMenu.add_command(label="Interest", command= self.printBalance)

        text = Entry(root)
        text.pack()

        w = Label(root, text="Current Balance:")
        w.pack()

        w = Label(root, text=balance)
        w.pack()


    def printBalance(self):
            a = text.get()
            print(a)



class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self, initial_balance=0):
        self.balance = initial_balance
    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount       
    def get_balance(self, initial_balance, rate):
        return self.get_balance() * self._rate











root = Tk()
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
root.title("Bank Account")
root.minsize(width=250, height=100)
root.maxsize(width=300, height=150)
GUI(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable in more than one method, you have to make it an instance variable by naming it with "self" on the front. In your case, change `text` to `self.text` in all the places you refer to it.